# Which display item under Fonts and Colors controls occurrence highlighting?

Tags: visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

Whenever I place my cursor somewhere within a type, variable name, or method name, Visual Studio highlights the item, along with all other occurrences of the type, variable name, or method name within the same source file. The problem is that the highlighting color makes it very difficult to read with the color scheme I'm used to.

Is there a "Display Item" within "Fonts and Colors" to change this color? Or is there a way to turn off this highlighting altogether?

Comment: In VS2017 I found it under 
`Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced -> Highlighting -> `

   *  Highlight references to symbol under cursor

   *  Highlight related keywords under cursor

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**What you're looking for is actually called "Highlighted Reference".** It's certainly an intuitive name once you know it, but perhaps not the first thing that pops into your mind if you don't. You can change the text and background colors of this option to anything you want:

[image: Changing "Highlighted Reference" color in VS Options]

I'm not sure how you could turn it off completely, but I also can't imagine why you'd want to...I use this all the time. You might be able to turn it off by setting the colors it uses to be the same as your default colors, although I'm not sure since I've never actually tried it.

Alternatively, if you find this feature distracting despite its  usefulness, you could make the effect less jarring by specifying a background color that is very similar to your default background color.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. I thought I had gone through every item in the list, but somehow I missed that one. And, you are correct, it does make sense once you know it.

Answer (score 1):

try going to Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors and setting the Collapsible Region background color to your editor background color.

good luck

visit [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vseditor/thread/55be12f4-8d3d-4c89-83f7-8c38ffc6e203)

Comment: This is not correct. "Collapsible Region" refers to the highlighting of an entire block of code when you hover over the +/- icon in the left margin of the editor. This is different from the identifier highlighting that the question is about.